# Proving solution to a PDE remains nonnegative.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

The following problem is taken from Question 3, Chapter 5 of:

D.R. Durran, Numerical Methods for Fluid Dynamics: With Applications to Geophysics,. 1. Texts in Applied Mathematics 32, DOI 10.1007/978-1-4419-6412-0 1

It states the following:

Show that if $ \phi(x, 0) \ge 0 $
, the solution to 
$ \frac{\partial \phi(x, t)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(c(x)\phi(x, t)) = 0 $ remains nonnegative for all $ t \ge 0 $. Assume $ c(x) $ and $ \phi(x,t) $ have continuous derivatives to simplify argument. Does the result generalise to 2 and 3 spatial dimenions?

Hint:
For $ \phi(x,t) \lt 0 $, must have a first time  $ t_{0} $ and some point $ x_{0} $ s.t. $ \phi(x_{0}, t_{0}) = 0 $ and $ \frac{\partial \phi(x_{0}, t_{0})}{\partial t} \lt 0 $. Show that this is not possible.

My solution:

$$ \frac{\partial \phi(x, t)}{\partial t} = - c^´\phi(x, t) - c(x)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\phi(x, t) $$
Evalutating above at $ (x_{0}, t_{0}) $ gives

$ \frac{\partial \phi(x_{0}, t_{0})}{\partial t} = - c(x_{0})\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\phi(x_{0}, t_{0}) $

Thus if $ \frac{\partial \phi(x_{0}, t_{0})}{\partial t} \lt 0 $ must have $ c(x_{0})\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\phi(x_{0}, t_{0}) \gt 0 $

At this point I do not know how to show this inequality. I haven`t used the relation $ \phi(x, 0) \ge 0 $ yet. But I cannot see how this can be used since we are looking for information at time $ t_{0} $, not $ t = 0 $. Furthermore, we know nothing about $ c(x) $.  Presumably I need to prove that if
$ c(x_{0}) \gt 0 $ 
then 
$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\phi(x_{0}, t_{0}) \lt 0 $ 
and if 
$ c(x_{0}) \lt 0 $ 
then 
$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\phi(x_{0}, t_{0}) \gt 0 $ thus showing that it is impossible to obtain $ \frac{\partial \phi(x_{0}, t_{0})}{\partial t} \lt 0 $.

I have proved that indeed $ \phi(x, t) $ remains nonnegative by the method of characteristics but I wanted to try proving it following the hint. As for the question of whether this result extends to 2 and 3 spatial dimensions; I believe it does but I am struggling to come up with a convincing explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi(x_0, t_0) > 0$ and $\phi(x_0, t_0) = 0$, then $\phi(x, t_0)<0$ for some $x$ slightly less than $x_0$.  Similarly if 
$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi(x_0, t_0) < 0$ and $\phi(x_0, t_0) = 0$ with some point $x$ slightly greater than $x_0$.

But the hint isn't quite so obvious as it seems.  For example, $\phi(x,t) = -t^2$ would not have such $x_0, t_0$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, I believe it has led me to the correct solution (below). However, as for the case of ϕ(x,t)=−t2, I believe this cannot be a solution. Upon subtituting this into the governing equation, the result leads to a contradiction where c(x) = f(t).

Comment: I didn't say that $\phi(x,t) = -t^2$ is a solution.  I said that it's not obvious that there would be a $t_0$ and $x_0$ with $\phi(x_0, t_0) = 0$ and $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}(x_0, t_0) < 0$.

Comment: Yes, I suppose the hint could do with some further clarification. But I think this is a rather perverse edge-case that you have identified! Perhaps it should say for ϕ(x,0)>0 instead. Do you have any advice for tackling the 2 and 3 dimensional case (see below)?

Comment: For the $2$ or $3$ dimensional case, again if there is such a point $(x_0, t_0)$ you must have $\nabla \phi(x_0, t_0) = 0$.  But 
$\nabla \cdot ({\bf c}(x) \phi(x,t)) = (\nabla \cdot {\bf c}(x)) \phi(x,t) + {\bf c} \cdot \nabla \phi(x,t)$, so this will be $0$ at $(x_0, t_0)$.

Comment: Assuming $\phi(x,0) > 0$ would not help.  Try $\phi(x,t) =  (1-t)^3$.

Answer (score 0):

If  $ \phi_{x}(x,t) \lt 0 $ then there exists an $ \epsilon \gt 0 $ with $ x_{1} + \epsilon $ such that $ \phi(x_{1},t_{0}) \lt 0 $. However, from the initial condition, $ \phi(x_{1},0) \gt 0 $ thus there must exist a $ t_{1} \in [0, t_{0}) $ s.t. $ \phi(x_{1},t_{1}) = 0 $ which is a contradiction against $ t_{0} $ being the first time s.t. $ \phi(x_{0}, t_{0}) = 0 $.

Similar argument applies for  $ \phi_{x}(x,t) \gt 0 $.

However, I still have not convinved myself for the case of 2 or 3 spatial dimensions where the governing equation is extended to:

$ \frac{\partial \phi(x, t)}{\partial t} + \nabla . (\textbf{c}(x)\phi(x, t)) = 0 $